# Dropzone, add each new file in the beginning of preview container

Tags: dropzone.js

I am using dropzone to handle file uploading and I am using preview container to specify the place where uploaded files should be shown.

So my configuration is the following (only relevant part is left):

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#fileUploadHandler",{
    previewsContainer: '.filesList'
});
```

The problem is that in that container I already show some files and the new files are downloaded in the end of the list. What I want to do is to add them in the beginning. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your dropzone.js file, find the code that adds the file preview to the preview container.  It should look like this:

```
if (this.previewsContainer) {
      file.previewElement = Dropzone.createElement(this.options.previewTemplate.trim());
      file.previewTemplate = file.previewElement;
      this.previewsContainer.appendChild(file.previewElement);
```

Change it to

```
if (this.previewsContainer) {
      file.previewElement = Dropzone.createElement(this.options.previewTemplate.trim());
      file.previewTemplate = file.previewElement;
      // check to see if there is already a child element in the preview container
      var previewFirstChild = this.previewsContainer.firstChild;
      if (previewFirstChild) {
        // if so, add the new file preview in front of the first child
        this.previewsContainer.insertBefore(file.previewElement, previewFirstChild);
      } else {
        // otherwise just append it 
        this.previewsContainer.appendChild(file.previewElement);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can not verify right now, if somebody find this working correctly - please CC me so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: there is no need to do this, you can prepend with native functionality.

Answer (score 5):

just prepend preview element to dropzone

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone('#fileUploadHandler', {
    init: function () {
        this.on('addedfile', function (file) {  
           $('#fileUploadHandler').prepend($(file.previewElement));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the best solution as it requires no hacking or overriding of the original plugin source code. You can also do this without jQuery like so:
`this.previewsContainer.insertBefore(file.previewElement, this.previewsContainer.firstChild);`.
Note that this does not alter the queue order that files are uploaded in.

Comment: it is a better answer, but it is not necessarily the best answer if you don't want to totally override the init functionality of dropzone, see my answer for how to do it without overriding init

Answer (score 1):

Create your dropzone instance

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#fileUploadHandler",{
  previewsContainer: '.filesList'
});
```

Then use the addedfile event to modify the preview with prepending instead of appending.

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file)
{
  jQuery('.filesList').prepend(jQuery(file.previewElement));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options without modifying the library source code.

1) Disable previewsContainer and handle the preview element in the *addedFile* event:

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone('#fileUploadHandler', {
    previewsContainer: false,
    init: function () {
        this.on('addedfile', function (file) {
            file.previewElement = Dropzone.createElement(this.options.previewTemplate.trim());

            var previews = document.getElementById('#previews');
            previews.insertBefore(file.previewElement, previews.firstChild);
        }
    }
});
```

2) Override the *addedfile* option:

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone('#fileUploadHandler', {
    previewsContainer: '.filesList',
    addedfile: function (file) {
        file.previewElement = Dropzone.createElement(this.options.previewTemplate.trim());

        this.previewsContainer.insertBefore(file.previewElement, this.previewsContainer.firstChild);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Note: When using one of these suggestions you have to handle some functionality yourself like the *addRemoveLinks* option and preview removal.